# How to create an image button with other elements after the image in Java

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In WPF(Windows Presentation Foundation) you can put an image into a button to create an image button, you can also add a text after that, not only one label but more, all on the same button.
My question is how can I do that in JSF with PrimeFaces or another component.
I have included a picture [image: here]

to let you understand what I did try and what I wanted, any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For JSF

```
 <p:commandButton value="Cancel" icon="ui-icon-myCancel" />
```

IN css

```
 .ui-icon-myCancel{
 background-image: url("#{resource['images/test.jpg']}") !important;
 }
```

JSP

Css:

```
input#image-button{
background: #ccc url('icon.png') no-repeat top left;
padding-left: 16px;
height: 16px;
```

}

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="image-button" value="Text"></input>
```

It will give you some hint

Comment: thank you @NTK88 , The _value_ for the _CommandButton_ and for the _input_ will be on the image not noxt to it, which is what i want, like "play sound" on the picture is next to the audio icon, thanks for your try.

Comment: It is working as an image button where the description of the image or (label) is "on" the image, i want it to be next to it "after" it but still on the button.